# C# Windows Service Stop Itself With Error Code

Tags: c#, service

I have developed a windows service that appears to be crashing occasionally.

In order to combat this i have written my method that is crashing into a try catch method that will log what the error is.

I then want to stop the service.

I know how to stop the service, by using the Stop() method, however i also want the service to restart after 10 minutes

I can do that with the recovery tab on the windows service

https://i.gyazo.com/b87020b24c9137abe2aa3cee8f7301fd.png

So what i want to know is, how can i stop the Windows Service in a way that the Service controller knows that it is a failure and not just a normal stop?

I have tried passing in an error code but this doesnt work

```
catch (Exception exep)
{

   Stop(1);
}
```

So how can i stop my service in a way the controller knows its an error and to restart it after ten minutes

Answer (score 1):

You could use below code block to stop the service

```
  service.Stop();
  service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

then start service after 10 min using

```
service.Start();
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

Comment: Hi, could i use this code within the service itself? I want the service itself to handle everything rather than need another program with the service controller

Comment: As per my knowledge it won't be possible in code it self.

but you could use the recovery option at the while starting service 
```
var startInfo = process.StartInfo;
  startInfo.FileName = "sc";
   startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        // This will restart service if it fails
        startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("failure \"{0}\" reset= 0 actions= restart/60000", serviceName);

        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        exitCode = process.ExitCode;
```

Comment: Alternatively Manual way is go to Window--> Service --> Locate the service --> right click --> Properties --> Recovery mode --> First failure (Restart the Service)